# Composite indexes not working on a relationship in Entity Framework

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

Indexes are not being set in the following, fully-working example.  Here is exactly [what I see in Visual Studio in my actual project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSyaT.jpg):

First time through. Adding 1190 rows from a UnitTest. This is one of the inserts shown in the context.Database.Log event.
[image]

EF obviously created the index
[image]

What the heck? My index is not listed.
[image]

So I insert a row.  INSERT INTO Programs (DispalyName ....
Tada. A whole whack of indexes, ****but only one inserted leaf****.
[image]

As expected I now have 1191 rows
[image]

So I run the test again to add another 1190 rows. As expected.
Now everything's getting a whack of indices. And look ****1191 leaf but there are 2381 rows in the programs table****.
[image]

And finally the real problem. The execution plan says nothing about using the index.
[image]

The index is being created but when it's being added as a relationship, it's not using the index.  No index leaves get created.

If I change:

```
//Join the relations
host.Programs.Add(program);

ctx.Hosts.Add(host);

//Save
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

To

```
ctx.Programs.Add(program);

//Save
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

The index works and I get leaves.  Any ideas?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Annotations;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;

namespace dbtest
{
    class ProgramTest
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Uses nuget package LocalDbApi
            //Start a localdb instance.  Delete the old one if necessary
            var localDb = new LocalDbApi.Instance();
            try { localDb.StopInstance("dust");} catch { }
            if (File.Exists("c:\\users\\james\\test.mdf")) File.Delete("c:\\users\\james\\test.mdf");
            if (File.Exists("c:\\users\\james\\test_log.ldf")) File.Delete("c:\\users\\james\\test_log.ldf");
            try { localDb.GetInstance("dust"); } catch { localDb.Create("dust"); }
            localDb.StartInstance("dust");

            //Create the Db
            Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<DustContext>());
            using (var ctx = new DustContext())
            {
                ctx.Database.Log = Console.Write;

                ctx.Database.Create();

                //Add the data
                var host = new Host()
                {
                    Hostname = "192.168.0.1",
                    Programs = new List<Program>()
                };
                var program = new Program()
                {
                    DisplayName = "foo",
                    Architecture = 1,
                    Disposition = 0,
                    Publisher = "bar",
                    Version = "14684"
                };

                //Join the relations
                host.Programs.Add(program);

                ctx.Hosts.Add(host);

                //Save
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }

            Console.Write("Press any key to continue ...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public class DustContext : DbContext
        {
            public DbContextConfiguration Config => Configuration;

            //My models
            public DbSet<Program> Programs { get; set; }
            public DbSet<Host> Hosts { get; set; }

            //Connection String
            public DustContext() : base(new SqlConnection() { ConnectionString = @"data source = (LocalDb)\dust;Trusted_Connection=False;Integrated Security=true;AttachDbFilename=c:\users\james\test.mdf"  }, true) { }

            protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
                base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
                modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ProgramMap());
            }
        }
    }


    /***************************************************************
     *
     *   Entities
     *
     ***************************************************************/

    public class Program
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        //Composite key on these three
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public string Publisher { get; set; }
        public string Version { get; set; }

        public Int32 Architecture { get; set; }
        public int Disposition { get; set; }
    }

    public class ProgramMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Program>
    {
        public ProgramMap()
        {
            Property(a => a.DisplayName)
                .HasMaxLength(512)
                .HasCompositeIndexAnnotation("IX_ProgramDisplayNamePublisherVersion", 1);
            Property(a => a.Publisher)
                .HasMaxLength(512)
                .HasCompositeIndexAnnotation("IX_ProgramDisplayNamePublisherVersion", 2);
            Property(a => a.Version)
                .HasMaxLength(512)
                .HasCompositeIndexAnnotation("IX_ProgramDisplayNamePublisherVersion", 3);
        }
    }

    public class Host
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Hostname { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Program> Programs { get; set; }
    }

}

/// <summary>
/// Applies an index on composite columns
/// </summary>
internal static class TypeConfigurationExtensions
{
    public static PrimitivePropertyConfiguration HasCompositeIndexAnnotation(
        this PrimitivePropertyConfiguration property,
        string indexName,
        int columnOrder)
    {
        var indexAttribute = new IndexAttribute(indexName, columnOrder) { IsUnique = false };
        var indexAnnotation = new IndexAnnotation(indexAttribute);

        return property.HasColumnAnnotation(IndexAnnotation.AnnotationName, indexAnnotation);
    }
}
```

Here's the output to the console:

> INSERT [dbo].Host VALUES (@0) SELECT [Id] FROM [dbo].[Host] WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [Id] = scope_identity()
>
> -- @0: '192.168.0.1' (Type = String, Size = -1)
>
> INSERT [dbo].[Program]([DisplayName], [Publisher], [Version], [Architecture], [D isposition], [Host_Id]) VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5) SELECT [Id] FROM [dbo].[Program] WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [Id] = scope_identity()
>
> -- @0: 'foo' (Type = String, Size = 512)
>
> -- @1: 'bar' (Type = String, Size = 512)
>
> -- @2: '14684' (Type = String, Size = 512)
>
> -- @3: '1' (Type = Int32)
>
> -- @4: '0' (Type = Int32)
>
> -- @5: '1' (Type = Int32)

If I actually run this against an empty database, it works.

```
BEGIN TRAN T1

INSERT [dbo].Host VALUES ('192.168.0.1') SELECT [Id] FROM [dbo].[Host] WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [Id] = scope_identity()

INSERT [dbo].[Program]([DisplayName], [Publisher], [Version], [Architecture], [Disposition], [Host_Id]) VALUES ('foo', 'bar', '14684', '1', '0', '1') SELECT [Id] FROM [dbo].[Program] WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [Id] = scope_identity()

COMMIT TRAN T1
```

Comment: @magicandre1981 .. how'd you do that?!  magic!